# Circuit operation and component substitution questions for stroboscopic timing light

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, bjt, inductance

I'm trying to make a piece of circuitry, for a tool used to set the ignition timing of my old car.

I've found the schematic and description here:

http://citroen.tramontana.co.hu/en/ignition/stroboscopic-timing-light

[image: stroboscopic timing light]

Do you think it is working properly?

But I made some changes and I don't know if it is OK:

- I used a [Nichia NFSL757GT LED](https://www.nichia.co.jp/specification/products/led_spec/NFSL757GT-E(3538D)R70%20R8000%20R9050.pdf), and I've regulated the current with two 220 ohm resistors in parallel. Is it OK?
- Instead of the [BD135](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00001225.pdf) BJT, I've used a [FZT651](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/FZT651.pdf). Is it OK?
- I can't understand the purpose of R1, D2 and C1. The author wrote that they protect the thyristor, but what does it mean? R1 and D2 are needed to regulate the voltage? And C1?
- is C1 a 220nF capacitor?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but I would use a Cree XP-3G  LED with a Ledil FA10653_LC1-RS (or similar) spot lens.

Comment: Thanks, the LED flux and the lens are not the problem now, I don't need a lot of lumens or a defined light pattern for this scope.

Comment: I've checked the datasheet, they are ok, thanks for adding

Comment: Is there anyone  who can give a piece of advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyone who can give a piece of advice?

There are some guys on her that are very good with transistor circuits, but I'm not one of them.  In my 40+ years I have never designed a circuit with a transistor.  My experience with transistors is from a class I took in 1974.

> I used a Nichia NFSL757GT LED, and I've regulated the current with two
> 220 ohm resistors in parallel. Is it OK?

It's okay, it will light up but it's a mid power LED capable of 180 mA so I would add another resistor or two (in parallel with the other two).  It not a particularly good choice.  I would use a high power 5700K or higher cool white.  With a spot lens.

> Do you think it is working properly?
>
> Instead of the BD135 BJT, I've used a FZT651. Is it OK?

I'm going to go with a no on these as a BD135 is an NPN and the FZT651 is a PNP.

> is C1 a 220nF capacitor?

Yes, most likely guess.  µF would be too big and pF too little.

> R1, D2 and C1. The author wrote that they protect the thyristor, but
> what does it mean?

The trigger signal is likely to have transient spikes that exceed the rating of the thyristor. C1 absorbs excess energy, the D2 redirects excessive voltage spikes to ground and the resistor is used to provide the voltage level required for the thyristor given the trigger level.  I'm almost guessing.  You seemed desperate, I tried.

---

I do know LEDs very well and I have used a Snap On timing light.  It was much brighter (xenon flash bulb) than a single 30 lumen mid powered LED.  And it had a lens.

If you do not want to use a SMT LED and lens,  then use a 30¢ Cree 5mm Round
LED part number: [C503D-WAN](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/C503D-WAN-935.pdf).  This has a 15° lens with 45,000 mcd of cool white which would equate to 2,400 lumens.  Your Nichia is about 30 lm @ 120° and is a warm white.  This app needs a cool white.

Comment: R1, D2, and C1 . almost always found gate to cathode in power circuits. Good answer overall.

Comment: Also, D2 prevent negative gate volts.

Comment: @Marla thanks, we studied vacuum tubes more than transistors in 1974.  Math was done with a slide rule.  In 1975 I got a TI SR-11 (slide rule 11)  four function calculator with square root.  Unfortunately no trig functions.  One phase angle example would take the instructor an hour using a slide rule and trig tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found a BLD128D, is it ok?

Comment: I do not know.  You should post another question "Can I substitute a BD128D in place of a BD135?" and include the image of the schematic.

Comment: thanks for the help. here the question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/394487/can-i-substitute-a-bd128d-in-place-of-a-bd135